# Windows Server Backup and Restore Command Line or pgAdmin

Tags: backup, postgresql, windows-command-prompt

Newbie to postgresql, I come from an Windows background with Backup Exec and Veritas GUI driven applications, I also have a Centos bacula background.

If this is in the wrong forum, please move.

I have a Windows Server with a postgreSQL database and looking into how to back it up and restore it with Windows command line or pgAdmin III.

I have used the pg_dump dbname > output file, and restore with psql dbname < infile.  I have seen the post with pg_dump does not include tablespaces, groups or users and pg_dump only dumps one of my databases in a cluster / instance.

I also use the pgAdmin III backup and restore

My questions are:

With the pg_dump are there better commands switches to backup individual databases or the whole sql file / all databases?

Can you schedule the pgAdmin III for nightly backups?

Thanks

TK

Comment: For sql backup Iam not an expert, but usually you have a export/commit to do, so it truncate the transaction log and it make a file recoverable. Over that I usually do another kind of backup, wbadmin or the one you need

Comment: So if I have 3 databases in PostgreSQL a .bat file would be:                         net stop postgresql-9.4
pg_dump dbname > outputfile
net start postgresql-9.4

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to backup PostgreSQL databases automatically according to the schedule then you can try PostgreSQL-Backup https://postgresql-backup.com it performs backups via pg_dump tool. Such backups can be easily restored via command prompt:

1. Go to Postgres bin folder. For example: cd "C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin"
2. Enter the command to restore your database. For example: psql.exe -U  -d  -f
3. Type password for your postgres user
4. Check the restore process